# How to design this Navbar in Bootstrap with the proper icons?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, glyphicons

I am a new web designer and I am struggling right now in designing a responsive navbar in bootstrap with the proper icons. **Could you please tell me which icons I should use for the following menu options?**

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Time Series</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Place Order</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!--/.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
```

Comment: You should also use [Font Awesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/), you'll get a wider icons catalog

Answer (score 1):

First time I see a request like this .. 
You're the designer, you should do whatever you want and don't need advices from others.

But since you asked it, here something you could start with : http://www.bootply.com/jePKaJ3ebg

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i> Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> Timeline</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i> Place a Request</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i> Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></i> Support <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

And as I commented, you could use [Font Awesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) to get a wider catalog, and IMO they are better designed than Bootstrap's glyphicons.